# Botones sobre imagen xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, botón, iphone

Tengo un problema al intentar colocar botones sobre una imagen.
Lo que quiero que haga la aplicación es llevarte a un nuevo View tras haber pulsado sobre el nombre de un corte de carne dentro del diagrama de la vaca.
La idea es que sea una app horizontal y que se ajuste al tamaño de pantalla de cualquier iPhone.

[image: xcode]

Después de aplicar los constraints de altura y ancho, el botón 1 desaparece en el sumulador.

[image: simulador]

¿Cuáles serían los constraints adecuados?
¿Existe algún componente adicional que pueda ser de ayuda?

Comment: Puedes utilizar un `View` de 300x300 que sirva de contenedor para la imagen y dentro de este view agregar los botones. Puedes agregar los constraint en tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, amigo. Funcionó a la perfección!